# digital to analog conversion

Tags: avr, codevisionavr

I have a SRF04 distance module and I don't want to use it with it's digital output. So I have to convert it to analog. To do that I bought a small AT-tiny micro controller.
Can help me how can I convert digital to analog. I'm using codevision-AVR program.

thanks a lot.
FDMX.

Comment: You'll need more then a DAC. That module simply returns a 'echo pulse' from a sonic burst it sent first. You'll need to calculate distance based on the time it takes for the echo to return.

Answer (score 0):

The SRF04 unit sends back a pulse to the ATTiny. You have to measure the time of the pulse using interrupts or polling. The time of the pulse will be 58 us times the distance in cm.

Once you have that number, you can use the ATTiny to convert the number to a voltage using PWM.

There are lots of code examples of both these things on the Internet. Search for AVR interrupts, and for PWM. Stack Overflow is not meant to be a place to repeat the examples for everyone who posts a question. If you get some code almost working, you can come back here to post your code and ask why is doesn't work.

Comment: thank you so much. I'm sorry about that, it wont happen again...!!